# Drawing Shapes and manipulation on shapes on android

Tags: android

i need to draw a shape and make manipulation on that shape.

for example like this, http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/2.5.1/editor/svg-editor.html

We draw the shapes on drawing area which is selected shape.

Pls give an idea how to do on android.

Answer (score 2):

You should draw your shapes onto a [`surfaceView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) using the android [`Graphics`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/package-summary.html).

Specifically with the use of a [`Canvas`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html).

Take a look at the offical [Lunar Landing Demo](http://jayxie.com/mirrors/android-sdk/resources/samples/LunarLander/index.html) for an example.

> You can find the source code for this sample in your SDK at:
>
> ```
> <sdk>/platforms/android-<version>/samples/
> ```

Comment: Is there anyway to do it using just the canvas only?

Comment: @Gaurav What use is a canvas, if it isnt attached to the screen? `surfaceView` is a `View` that you can draw onto using the canvas.

Comment: What do you mean by not attached to the screen? Sorry for asking lame questions.

Comment: @Gaurav a canvas is just an object you draw on. It does not display on screen. Unless you specify a view to show the canvas. SurfaceView is essentially a wrapper around the canvas, that displays the canvas on screen.